# How to use get_file_content after use str_replace

Tags: php, string, replace, match, file-get-contents

I have problem with using get_file_content after preg_match and str_replace.

When I read from base, text look like:

```
Some text with shortcodes: [formularz {"agree":"1,1,1","option":"firstname,lastname,phone,email,company","leadfrom":"Allegro"}] [formularz {"agree":"0,1,0","option":"firstname,lastname,phone","leadfrom":"Allegro"}]
```

Then I looking my regular '[]':

```
preg_match_all('/\[formularz (.*)\]/',$campaign['content'],$matches);
```

Then I replace some chars and words:

```
echo str_replace($matches[0],str_replace([':','","','"','{','}'],['=','&','','file_get_contents("http:// mydomain.com/form.php?id_added_to_lead='.$id_added_to_lead.'&','")'],$matches[1]),str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "
",stripslashes($campaign['content']))) ;
```

And finally I have:

```
Some text with shortcodes:

file_get_contents("http:// mydomain.com/form.php?id_added_to_lead=100&agree=1,1,1&option=firstname,lastname,phone,email,company&leadfrom=Allegro")

file_get_contents("http:// mydomain.com/form.php?id_added_to_lead=100&agree=0,1,0&option=firstname,lastname,phone&leadfrom=Allegro")
```

What should I do, If I want to execute file_get_content in content?

Comment: `urlencode` but you could save alot of work with `json_decode` and `http_build_query`.

Comment: I know how kreate a http query, but I dont know how execute <pre>file_get_content</pre> inside a result of str_replace

or please show me How reconfigure this script to work